# Open Pdf in cordova app

Tags: cordova, pdf

I want to open PDF file from URL within app screen without open any inappbrowser or external app please tell me is there is any solution for this

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for PDF Reader plugins:

1. https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer (Recommended)
2. https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2
3. https://github.com/etabard/Cordova-PDFReader-IOS

Regards.

Comment: `cordova-plugin-document-viewer` was last updated in 2014 and doesn't appear to work on iOS as of 2021. `cordova-plugin-file-opener2` works well though.